# Angular Karma Jasmine - test function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Basically i have to test this below function, where i'm reading from text file

```
$window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (dir) {
    var path = 'somefile.txt';                    
    dir.getFile(path, { create: true }, function (file) {
        file.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {                               
                resolve(this.result);
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }, error); 
}, error);
```

i'm stuck in writing the unit test cases for reading file

```
describe('get data from file', function () {            

    it('should read the files from the data', function () {
        var syncFile = 'somefile.txt';

        expect( ).toBe( );
    });
});
```

How to write unit test for filereader for reading the file?
PS : i'm new to unit testing using karma

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use FileReader directly. Change that line to

```
var reader = new $window.FileReader();
```

In your test mock the $window and return a custom FileReader object. Then do the tests on that. Something like below.

```
describe('get data from file', function () {

    var $window, fileReader;

    beforeEach(function () {

        inject(function (_$window_) {
            $window = _$window_;
        });

        fileReader = function () {
            return {};
        };

        spyOn($window, "FileReader").and.returnValue(fileReader);
    });

    it('should read the files from the data', function () {
        var syncFile = 'somefile.txt';

        expect($window.FileReader).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

Comment: can you please explain how this is executed?

Comment: @Matarishvan Which portion you do not understand? Overall, it creates a spy for the FileReader method in the window object. Then you can use this spy to inject your own intended behaviour and track and test the calls made to that method.

Comment: So basically i have to pass my exact function in my expect function?. Not getting the expect to to be and how to use it?

Comment: @Matarishvan I have updated the expect statement. Basically, this one tests if your method was called. Same way you can spy on dummy functions that the FileReader call returns. And test them using expect. Please have a look at the Jasmine documentation first. https://jasmine.github.io/

Comment: OK? so `somefile.txt` is just the mock file? correct?.. Here i don't have to specify exact file. My understanding is here you are just checking if `FileReader` function is called or not..

Comment: @Matarishvan Remember that when Unit testing, you're testing small units of code. 

You're not directly testing the FileReader implementation. You likely need to write a test that verifies that reader.readAsText was called and that a new instance of FileReader was created. 

You don't need to directly test the actual FileReader. You'll also likely want to test potential errors are handled correctly, e.g. read errors . You can mock the FileReader and force it to throw an error when the appropriate method is called. Verify with a spy that the error handler ran.

Comment: @Matarishvan Yes the comment above from Daniel is correct. When unit testing, you don't bother about the flow outside of the unit (function, class etc) you are testing. You mock all the external dependencies and just test whether they were called or not. But, anyway if you need to test the whole integration, don't mock FileReader. Instead of spyOn($window, "FileReader").and.returnValue(fileReader) which returns a mock file reader, use spyOn($window, "FileReader").and.callThrough(fileReader); This would actually go ahead and call the file reader. Of course, this is not a good practice.